# Should I use StreamReader/Writer with NetworkStream for C# server/client?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, streamreader

I'm in the process of building a client/server based game for a project(feeling quite out my depth). I've been using TCPclient and a multi-threaded socket server. Everything is working fine at the moment but I have been using StreamReader and StreamWriter to communicate between both client and server.

I keep seeing examples like this for recieving data:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
```

and this for sending:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test message");
server.SendTo(data, iep);
```

I was wondering what are the benefits of using this over streamReader? Would using this also be buffering?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a different style. `ReceiveFrom` and `SendTo` are more Unix-style, and using a `StreamReader` is more of a .NET style. `StreamReader` would be of more use to you, as you could then pass it to other methods that accept a `TextReader`.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I am going to be sticking with streamReader but would like to know if it provides any buffering?

Comment: I don't know whether it adds any buffering. I doubt it. However, the underlying stream certainly has some buffering of the network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

`sendTo()` and `receiveFrom()` are used for connection less sockets, that use UDP as the transport protocol. You can use `Send()` or `Recieve()` when using connection oriented or stream sockets that use TCP as the protocol.
StreamReader and StreamWriter are the classes of IO namespace that will help in solving the message boundary problem that come with TCP sockets.
Message boundary problem means that all send calls are not picked up in all receive calls.
To avoid the message boundary problem we use networkstream with streamreader and streamwriter.